# Eigenlib and performance of small matrix operations

Tags: c++, performance, blas, eigen3, avx2

I chose eigenlib for my project, since I deal with a lot of small scale vector- and matrix-operations. Naturally, I implemented the simple the vector-Matrix-vector product in eigenlib as this function:

```
const int dims = 2;

template <typename T>
using Vec = Eigen::Matrix<T, dims, 1>;

template <typename T>
using Mat = Eigen::Matrix<T, dims, dims>;

template <typename T>
inline auto quadraticMetricNorm(const Vec<T>& x1, const Vec<T>& x2, const Mat<T>& D)
{
    return x1.transpose() * D * x2;
}
```

I expected that the resulting code would be similar to a handcrafted solution:

```
template <typename T>
inline auto quadraticMetricNorm(const Vec<T>& x1, const Vec<T>& x2, const Mat<T>& D)
{
    return (x1(0, 0) * D(0, 0) + x1(1, 0) * D(1, 0)) * x2(0, 0) 
         + (x1(0, 0) * D(0, 1) + x1(1, 0) * D(1, 1)) * x2(1, 0);
}
```

and even a bit quicker if I activated AVX2, but after some testing I found out that the handcrafted solution is nearly 3 times as fast according to my profiler in my project. Did I do something wrong, or is Eigenlib's performance just inferior for these small scale problems?

Example:

```
int main()
{
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 mt(rd());
    uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(1.0, 10.0);

    std::chrono::nanoseconds total{};
    const uint64_t max_loops = 10000000;
    std::vector<double> arr(max_loops);

    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < max_loops; i++)
    {
        Vec<double> x1;
        x1 << dist(mt), dist(mt);

        Vec<double> x2;
        x2 << dist(mt), dist(mt);

        Mat<double> D;
        D << dist(mt), dist(mt), dist(mt), dist(mt);

        auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        arr[i] = quadraticMetricNorm(x1, x2, D);
        total += chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start);
    }

    cout << "Loop took " << total.count() / 1000000 << "ms" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Loop took ~850ms for the first version vs. ~440ms for the second version on my computer.

I'm running Intel i7-5820K CPU on Visual Studio Community 2017, with activated AVX2 in Release mode (Maximize Speed (/O2)).

Thank you for your help in advance!

### Edit

Since requested, here are the two assemblies. The faster one:

```
addsd   xmm1, xmm0
mulsd   xmm1, xmm10
mulsd   xmm12, xmm7
mulsd   xmm13, xmm9
addsd   xmm12, xmm13
mulsd   xmm12, xmm11
addsd   xmm1, xmm12
```

The generated code from Eigenlib is much more complex (no AVX2):

```
lea r8, QWORD PTR D$11[rbp-256]
lea rdx, QWORD PTR $T7[rbp-256]
lea rcx, QWORD PTR $T3[rsp]
call    ??$?DV?$Matrix@N$01$01$0A@$01$01@Eigen@@@?$MatrixBase@V?$Transpose@$$CBV?$Matrix@N$01$00$0A@$01$00@Eigen@@@Eigen@@@Eigen@@QEBA?BV?$Product@V?$Transpose@$$CBV?$Matrix@N$01$00$0A@$01$00@Eigen@@@Eigen@@V?$Matrix@N$01$01$0A@$01$01@2@$0A@@1@AEBV?$MatrixBase@V?$Matrix@N$01$01$0A@$01$01@Eigen@@@1@@Z ; Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::Matrix<double,2,1,0,2,1> const > >::operator*<Eigen::Matrix<double,2,2,0,2,2> >
mov rcx, rax
lea r8, QWORD PTR x2$9[rbp-256]
lea rdx, QWORD PTR $T5[rsp]
call    ??$?DV?$Matrix@N$01$00$0A@$01$00@Eigen@@@?$MatrixBase@V?$Product@V?$Transpose@$$CBV?$Matrix@N$01$00$0A@$01$00@Eigen@@@Eigen@@V?$Matrix@N$01$01$0A@$01$01@2@$0A@@Eigen@@@Eigen@@QEBA?BV?$Product@V?$Product@V?$Transpose@$$CBV?$Matrix@N$01$00$0A@$01$00@Eigen@@@Eigen@@V?$Matrix@N$01$01$0A@$01$01@2@$0A@@Eigen@@V?$Matrix@N$01$00$0A@$01$00@2@$0A@@1@AEBV?$MatrixBase@V?$Matrix@N$01$00$0A@$01$00@Eigen@@@1@@Z ; Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::Matrix<double,2,1,0,2,1> const >,Eigen::Matrix<double,2,2,0,2,2>,0> >::operator*<Eigen::Matrix<double,2,1,0,2,1> >
; File ...\eigenlib\eigen\src\core\coreevaluators.h

; 155  :     : m_data(m.data()), m_outerStride(IsVectorAtCompileTime ? 0 : m.outerStride()) 

lea rax, QWORD PTR $T10[rbp-240]
mov QWORD PTR $T10[rbp-256], rax
; File ...\eigenlib\eigen\src\core\cwisebinaryop.h

; 105  :       : m_lhs(aLhs), m_rhs(aRhs), m_functor(func)

movups  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR $T5[rsp]
movups  XMMWORD PTR $T6[rsp+8], xmm0
mov rax, QWORD PTR $T5[rsp+16]
mov QWORD PTR $T6[rbp-232], rax
; File ...\eigenlib\eigen\src\core\redux.h

; 453  :   return derived().redux(Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<Scalar,Scalar>());

lea rdx, QWORD PTR $T1[rsp]
lea rcx, QWORD PTR $T6[rsp]
call    ??$redux@U?$scalar_sum_op@NN@internal@Eigen@@@?$DenseBase@V?$CwiseBinaryOp@U?$scalar_product_op@NN@internal@Eigen@@$$CBV?$Transpose@$$CBV?$Product@V?$Transpose@$$CBV?$Matrix@N$01$00$0A@$01$00@Eigen@@@Eigen@@V?$Matrix@N$01$01$0A@$01$01@2@$0A@@Eigen@@@3@$$CBV?$Matrix@N$01$00$0A@$01$00@3@@Eigen@@@Eigen@@QEBANAEBU?$scalar_sum_op@NN@internal@1@@Z ; Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double,double>,Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::Matrix<double,2,1,0,2,1> const >,Eigen::Matrix<double,2,2,0,2,2>,0> const > const ,Eigen::Matrix<double,2,1,0,2,1> const > >::redux<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double,double> >
movsd   QWORD PTR $T10[rbp-240], xmm0
```

So Visual Studio and Eigenlib simply do not get along very well together?

Comment: Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code.

Comment: With clang, both versions take 180ms (Haswell 2.6GHz), but be careful with such benchmark about 1) aggressive compiler and 2) the fact that there is really too few computations within two time stamps. I would recommend you to look for differences in the generated assembly, there is no reason for them to be different (expect that MSVC is not very good...)

Comment: As expected from my previous comment, if I replace the call to `quadraticMetricNorm` by `x1.x()`, then I get 177ms, so you're not benchmarking anything relevant.

Comment: OK, from your assembly it is pretty clear that MSVC failed to generate a proper code because some trivial functions have not been inlined (we can see the calls). Are you sure you enabled full compiler optimizations? I cannot believe that MSVC is that bad at inlining.

Comment: BTW, writing `x1.dot(D * x2)` might helps MSVC to do its job, but I really think that you are missing a compiler option. MSVC has never been really good at inlining, but I never seen something that bad. Or maybe they completely rewrote their inlining heuristics in the 2017 version, with severe shortcomings...

Comment: Could you try what happens if you make `quadraticMetricNorm` return `T` instead of `auto`? (generally, avoid using `auto` for results of Eigen operations)

Comment: chtz's comment is relevant, especially when using the `.transpose() *` version which returns an expression. After fixing your code to prevent the compiler from removing everything (I added `return arr[argc];`), I get 241ms for Eigen vs 263ms for the handwritten code thanks to explicit vectorization for the Eigen version. Recall that among these 241ms, 180ms are spent in calls to `high_resolution_clock`., so the relative difference is 61ms vs 83ms.